# Firebase response returns 200 but empty array

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am currently working with Firebase and Firebase functions. I am trying to get documents within a collection (collection : 'items'). I tried doing a GET, however I only get a 200 and empty body.

```
app.get('/api/read/items', (req, res) => {
(async () => {
    try {
        let response = [];
        let itemRefs = db.collection('items').get().then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach((item) => {
                response.push(item.data());
            });
            console.log(response);
        });
        return res.send(response);
    } catch (error) {
        debug.log(error);
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
})();
});
```

[image: Firebase collection screenshot]

Interestingly when I query a specific item, I get the JSON body with the document data included:

```
app.get('/api/read/:item_id', (req, res) => {
(async () => {
    try {
        const document = db.collection('items').doc(req.params.item_id);
        let item = await document.get();
        let response = item.data();
        return res.status(200).send(response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
})();
});
```

Looking forward to see what mistake I made :)!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is loaded form Firestore asynchronously. By the time your `res.send(response)` executes, the `snapshot.forEach(...)` hasn't been run yet.

The solution is to send the response to the client from within the innermost callback:

```
app.get('/api/read/items', (req, res) => {
(async () => {
    try {
        let response = [];
        return db.collection('items').get().then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach((item) => {
                response.push(item.data());
            });
            console.log(response);
            return res.send(response);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        debug.log(error);
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
})();
});
```

---

Alternative, you can use `await` as you do in your second snippet:

```
app.get('/api/read/items', (req, res) => {
(async () => {
    try {
        let response = [];
        let snapshot = await snapshot db.collection('items').get();
        snapshot.forEach((item) => {
            response.push(item.data());
        });
        return res.send(response);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
})();
});
```

Which you can simplify a bit further to:

```
app.get('/api/read/items', (req, res) => {
(async () => {
    try {
        let snapshot = await snapshot db.collection('items').get();
        let response = snapshot.documents.map((item) => item.data());
        return res.send(response);
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    }
})();
});
```

Comment: Hi Frank, Thanks for the fast response, I tried the provided code snippet, however I got the same response unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you for the improved code. I think I found the issue, but I am not sure I fully understand the root cause. I will add the code below.

Comment: Your answer includes the changes I proposed it seems, so I'm quite sure those contribute to it now working.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the root cause of the problem, which I can not explain why, due to the lack of knowledge I have with node/express.
As I was testing I have my index.js file which contains :

```
const serviceAccount = require("./permissions.json");
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const db = admin.firestore();
......
app.get('/api/read/items', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            let response = [];
            return db.collection('items').get().then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach((item) => {
                    response.push(item.data());
                });
                console.log(response);
                return res.send(response);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
});

// read item
app.get('/api/read/:item_id', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const document = db.collection('items').doc(req.params.item_id);
            let item = await document.get();
            let response = item.data();
            return res.status(200).send(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
});


app.get('/api/read/geoFencedUsers', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            let response = [];
            return db.collection('geoFencedUsers').get().then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach((geoFencedUser) => {
                    response.push(geoFencedUser.data());
                });
                return res.status(200).send(response);
            })
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
});
```

Trying to do a GET call on read/geoFencedUsers return 200 but an empty response.
After changing my index.js literally moving that get method above, solved the problem making all 3 calls work returning a proper response with data.:

```
app.get('/api/read/items', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            let response = [];
            return db.collection('items').get().then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach((item) => {
                    response.push(item.data());
                });
                console.log(response);
                return res.send(response);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
});

app.get('/api/read/geoFencedUsers', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            let response = [];
            return db.collection('geoFencedUsers').get().then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach((geoFencedUser) => {
                    response.push(geoFencedUser.data());
                });
                return res.status(200).send(response);
            })
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
});

// read item
app.get('/api/read/:item_id', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const document = db.collection('items').doc(req.params.item_id);
            let item = await document.get();
            let response = item.data();
            return res.status(200).send(response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    })();
});
```